# How to find lattice points on a line segment?

Tags: equation-solving, geometry, number-theory, diophantine-equations

How do I find points on the line segment joining `{-4, 11}` and `{16, -1}` whose coordinates are positive integers?

Comment: Thanks for the accept - you could also wait a few days to encourage different answers and then choose the best one. You can also change the accept at any time (not that I mind if you keep it where it is).

Comment: Do you want all the lattice points on the line, or just those on the line segment between the two given points?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is this what you are searching for?

```
a = {-4, 11};
b = {16, -1};

dy = (b[[2]] - a[[2]])/(b[[1]] - a[[1]]);

offset = u /. Solve[a[[2]] == dy*a[[1]] + u, u][[1]];

coords = {x, 
   y} /. {Reduce[y == dy*x + offset && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}, 
     Integers] // ToRules}
```

> (*    {{1, 8}, {6, 5}, {11, 2}} *)

```
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{a, b}], Red, Point[coords], 
  Line[{a, b}]}, Axes -> True, GridLines -> {Range[16], Range[16]}, 
 ImageSize -> 640]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 27):

There are many ways to proceed, the best one uses [`FrobeniusSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html?q=FrobeniusSolve&lang=en) :

**I**

Since we know, that

```
a x + b == y /. Solve[{-4 a + b == 11, 16 a + b == -1}, {a, b}] // Simplify
```

> ```
> {3 x + 5 y == 43}
> ```

we find

```
FrobeniusSolve[ {3, 5}, 43]
```

> ```
> {{1, 8}, {6, 5}, {11, 2}}
> ```

a bit more straightforward way :

**II**

```
{x, y} /. Solve[ (a x + b == y /. Solve[ {-4 a + b == 11, 16 a + b == -1}, {a, b}])  
                  ~  Join  ~  {x > 0, y > 0}, {x, y}, Integers]
```

> ```
> {{1, 8}, {6, 5}, {11, 2}}
> ```

Comment: gotta love `FrobeniusSolve`

Comment: @cartonn This cannot be overcome by anything else in such cases.

Comment: +1 for casting the problem in a way that never occurred to me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, last answers are usually underestimated.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) with `Solve`, `Reduce` or `Eliminate`:

```
  a = {-4, 11}; b = {16, -1};
  coords =  Solve[y == InterpolatingPolynomial[{a, b}, x] && 0 <= x <= 16&&0<=y,
     {x, y}, Integers][[All, All, 2]];
  (* or *)
  coords={ToRules[Reduce[ y == InterpolatingPolynomial[{a, b}, x] && 
      0 <= x <= 16&&0<=y,  {x, y}, Integers]]}[[All, All, 2]];
  (* or *)
  coords = FindInstance[y == InterpolatingPolynomial[{a, b}, x] && 0 <= x <= 16&&0<=y, 
      {x, y},  Integers, 5][[All, All, 2]]
```

All three give

```
  { {1, 8}, {6, 5}, {11, 2}}
```

To show in a plot:

```
  Plot[InterpolatingPolynomial[{a, b}, x], {x, -5, 17},
    Mesh -> {First /@ coords}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 20}, {-2, 15}}]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can also use the plain old `Interpolation` in all of the above. For example,

```
  FindInstance[ y == Quiet@Interpolation[{a, b}][x] && 0 <= x <= 16 && 0 <= y,
      {x, y}, Integers, 5][[All, All, 2]]
  (* {{1, 8}, {6, 5}, {11, 2}} *)
```

**Update 2:** Getting into `Cases`, `Select`, `Pick` ... territory:

```
  Cases[{#, Interpolation[{a, b}, InterpolationOrder -> 1][#]} & /@ 
       Range[0, 16], {_Integer, _Integer?Positive}]
```

or

```
 Cases[{#, InterpolatingPolynomial[{a, b}, #]} & /@ 
         Range[0, 16], {_Integer, _Integer?Positive}]
```

Comment: +1, never used that before... very useful and another proof that we live to learn.

Comment: @Yves thanks for the vote. Learned about it just yesterday while struggling with `Interpolation` :)

Comment: Nice idea.  Incidentally, I noticed, in editing the question, that it stipulates the solutions should have *positive* coordinates.

Comment: @whuber, good point - funny I missed 50% of the requirements in a single-line question:) I will update with the added constraints.

Comment: @kguler `FindInstance` is not a way to go. Could you really solve this problem having initially e.g. these points `{{-4, 10313}, {16, 10301}}` ?

Comment: @artes, this sounded like a trick question; so it felt wiser to reply "Of course not ...". But, out of curiousity, I tried the inputs you suggested, and got `{{1, 10310}, {6, 10307}, {11, 10304}, {16, 10301}}` (almost, in no time). So, then ...  "why not?" (or else, I am missing something?)

Comment: @artes, ... then again, I would not suggest any of these against `FrobeniusSolve` in a speed and/or elegance contest :) (Btw, I need to train my memory to think of `FrobeniusSolve` first when I hear the keywords "integer, positive, solution.")

Comment: @kguler It is not surprising that `FindInstance` found something, but it doesn't says how many solutions there are. If there are none, you can't be sure working with it. Perhaps I'm prejudiced against it, nevertheless I can't find it very helpful or I'haven't seen really nice examples ot its usage. And at last I understand this task to find all points and when there are thousands it is not constructive. This was my only objection.

Comment: @artes, agreed.

Comment: @kguler I haven't tested your solution but shouldn't there be `y > 0` instead of `y <= 0` ?

Comment: @Artes, yes ... Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Artes's solution is the best, I think. If you just want to treat this as an ordinary Diophantine problem, you can do that with `Solve[]` (making this approach more or less equivalent to Yves's):

```
{p, q} = {-4, 11};
{r, s} = {16, -1};
{x, y} /. Solve[{(q - s) x - (p - r) y == -Det[{{p, q}, {r, s}}],
                 x > 0, y > 0, Min[p, r] < x < Max[p, r], Min[q, s] < y < Max[q, s]},
                {x, y}, Integers]
   {{1, 8}, {6, 5}, {11, 2}}
```

---

One could also choose to use [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) to solve this problem (see for instance [this excellent math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20727) by Arturo Magidin).

Luckily, `ExtendedGCD[]` is a built-in function for performing the extended Euclidean algorithm, so let's use that:

```
{g, v} = ExtendedGCD[q - s, p - r]
   {4, {2, 1}}
```

We check something first:

```
w = -Det[{{p, q}, {r, s}}];
Divisible[w, g]
   True
```

So a particular solution is then given by

```
f = w v/g
   {86, -43}
```

We can derive a parametrized set of solutions like so:

```
sols[k_] = Simplify[f + (k - Max[Quotient[w v, {p - r, q - s}]]) {p - r, q - s}/g]
   {11 - 5 k, 2 + 3 k}
```

As it turns out, `sols[0]` gives one of the needed solutions, and stepping forward (i.e. `sols[1]` and `sols[2]`) gives the others. If you're lazy, however, then you can use `FindInstance[]`:

```
Map[sols, k /.
    FindInstance[Thread[sols[k] > 0] ~Join~
                 Thread[Min /@ {{p, q}, {r, s}} <= sols[k] <= Max /@ {{p, q}, {r, s}}],
                 k, Integers, 3]]
   {{11, 2}, {6, 5}, {1, 8}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we know the equation of line through the two points, one can generate all points on the line with integer `x` and of them keep those with integer `y`. Without invoking solving function.

```
With[{x1 = -4, y1 = 11, x2 = 16, y2 = -1},
  Table[{x, (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) (x - x1) + y1},
   {x, x1, x2}]] // Cases[#, {_, _Integer}] &

(* {{-4, 11}, {1, 8}, {6, 5}, {11, 2}, {16, -1}} *)
```

Put this in `Manipulate` and you have an interactive canvas, showing the points on a segment between the end points which can me moved around the lattice.

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{x1, y1, x2, y2, pts},
  {x1, y1} = Round@p1;
  {x2, y2} = Round@p2;
  pts = Table[{x, (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) (x - x1) + y1},
     {x, x1, x2}] // Cases[#, {_, _Integer}] &;
  Graphics[{
    Gray, Line[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}],
    Black, PointSize[.01], Point[pts]},
   GridLines -> {Range[-10, 20], Range[-5, 15]},
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   Frame -> True,
   ImageSize -> 500,
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 20}, {-5, 15}}]],
 {{p1, {-4, 11}}, Locator},
 {{p2, {16, -1}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Quiet[Cases[Outer[List, Range[-4, 11], Range[16, -1, -1]], 
    {x_, y_} /; (y - 11)/(x + 4) == (y + 1)/(x - 16), {2}]]
```

This solution shows how to transform linear complexity to quadratic, and provides some relief of the comic variety. ;)