# Compact form for domain ranges of many variables

Tags: equation-solving

When one sets up an equation to solve one often needs to specify conditions on the variables such as

```
{ x>0 && y>0 && z>0 }
```

This is not a problem if only a few variables are involved. However, it is another matter when say, 50 are required. Is there a compact form one can use? Using

```
(...) && Table[x[[i]], {i,50}] > 0
```

within `Reduce[]` or `Solve[]` will not work.

Comment: Can you please format your question properly? Read [this here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) which you find when you click on the question mark of the editor window.

Comment: Try `(...) && (And @@ Table[...])`

Comment: The second solution to this answer:[How to find lattice points on a line segment?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16678/how-to-find-lattice-points-on-a-line-segment/16705#16705) is another example like one can use Solve. Perhaps you could see also this [Solve an equation in R+](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/solve-an-equation-in-mathbbr/14188#14188)

Answer (score 3):

One approach:

```
eqs = {x^2 + 4 y^2 + 9 z^2 + 16 t^2 == 354};

vars = Variables @ Level[eqs, -1]

Reduce[eqs ~Join~ Thread[vars > 0], {}, Integers]
```

> ```
> {t, x, y, z}
>
> (t == 1 && x == 1 && y == 8 && z == 3) || (t == 1 && x == 7 && y == 4 && z == 5) ||
> (t == 2 && x == 1 && y == 4 && z == 5) || (t == 2 && x == 5 && y == 8 && z == 1) || 
> (t == 2 && x == 7 && y == 2 && z == 5) || (t == 4 && x == 1 && y == 2 && z == 3) || 
> (t == 4 && x == 5 && y == 4 && z == 1)
> ```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks.

Comment: @TCJones You're welcome.  Please consider [voting for](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) posts you find helpful and [Accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) those that are fully satisfactory.