# Is there an analogue of the Variables command for general expressions?

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation, system-variables, filtering

The command

```
Variables[poly]
```

gives me a list of all variables that appear in the expression `poly`, which involved sums, products, and rational powers. Sadly, it doesn't work for more complicated expressions, such as trigonometric functions. I was wondering if there is another command that can handle expressions such as $\sin(x)+\cos(y)$.

Comment: Check [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/extracting-variables-from-an-expression) for some methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, d, h, p, m, f, g, a, w];

expr = Sin[x] + Cos[y] + z^3 + Exp[d] + h + 3 h^2 + 4 h^3 + 
   Integrate[Exp[p], p] + 
   D[Sin[m]^Exp[f], m]*Series[Sin[g], {g, 0, 3}] + 
   2 (E^a BesselK[0, 2 Sqrt[E^a]]) C[2]/D[Gamma[w], {w, 2}];

Cases[Variables[Level[expr, -1]], x_ /; AtomQ[x] :> x]

(* {a, d, f, g, h, m, p, w, x, y, z} *)
```

Comment: Nice - but you could use `Level[expr, {-1}]`, right?

Comment: @Jens That's what I did in my answer.  Nasser, forgive me but your current form doesn't make sense; you're effectively testing for indivisibility twice now: once with `{-1}` and once with `AtomQ`.  You should either just subsume/supplant my answer or go back to the original form.  (You're the one who encouraged me to post an answer; I'd have been glad to simply edit yours.)

Comment: Yes, both `-1` and `{-1}` will work in your code; that's my point.  With `{-1}` the `AtomQ` becomes redundant; that's why it's not in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Using Nasser's expression code as an example:

```
expr = Sin[x] + Cos[y] + z^3 + Exp[d] + h + 3 h^2 + 4 h^3 + 
   Integrate[Exp[p], p] + 
   D[Sin[m]^Exp[f], m]*Series[Sin[g], {g, 0, 3}] + 
   2 (E^a BesselK[0, 2 Sqrt[E^a]]) C[2]/D[Gamma[w], {w, 2}];
```

You might use:

```
Variables @ Level[expr, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {a, d, f, g, h, m, p, w, x, y, z}
> ```

To extract indexed variables such as `C[2]` you could use:

```
Cases[expr, _[_Integer], {-2}]
```

> ```
> {C[2]}
> ```

Comment: I almost overlooked your answer because it's so short... but it's obviously the easiest way!

Comment: @Jens I used the method [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29908/121) as well, but there I used `-1` rather than `{-1}` because I wanted to allow for indexed variables like `x[1]`.  Do you think I should try to extend my answer to handle *both* in `Sin[z] + x[1]`, that is include `z` and `x[1]` in the output list?

Comment: The OP was looking for an analogue of `Variables` for polynomials, and that limits what he means by variables. But indeed, that would also include things like `x[1]`!

Comment: +1  But what about something a term like `Integrate[Sqrt[1 + Exp[p^2]], {p, 0, 1}]`, which doesn't evaluate but is a constant?  Just live with it?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I guess it all depends on what you need; this is intended as the "simple" answer to complement more involved ones such as what Daniel linked to.  Most of the time I think it works OK.

Comment: I couldn't think of one and was just curious if there was an easy solution.  I love the elegance and efficacy of this one. -- Aha! Found something: Apply `Pick[#, Normal@D[expr, #] =!= 0 & /@ #] &` to results.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't understand; what should I be seeing? (Sorry, I only noticed this comment now.)

Comment: I meant if one replaces the integral in `expr` with a definite integral like `Integrate[Sqrt[1 + Exp[p^2]], {p, 0, 1}]`, then `Pick[#, Normal @ D[expr, #] =!= 0 & /@ #] &@ Variables @ Level[expr, {-1}]` returns `{a, d, f, g, h, m, w, x, y, z}` -- no `p`, which is only a "dummy" variable of integration. (My two previous comments are meant to go together.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Got it; thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[GetVariables]
SetAttributes[GetVariables, HoldFirst];
GetVariables[expr_, f_:Identity,  excludedContexts:{__String}:{"System`"}]:=
Cases[Unevaluated[expr], 
  a_Symbol/;!Or[
       MemberQ[excludedContexts, Context[a]],
       MemberQ[Attributes[a], Locked | ReadProtected]
    ] :> f[a], 
  {0, Infinity}
]//DeleteDuplicates
```

It is used like

```
GetVariables @ {Exp[f[x]], Sin[x y^2]}
(* {x, y} *)
```

or, if you need to

```
GetVariables[{Exp[f[x]], Sin[x y^2]}, Hold]
(* {Hold[x], Hold[y]} *)
```

By default, it excludes the `` System` `` context, but other contexts can be specified, too.

Answer (score 3):

```
sr = {Exp[v_] :> v, v1_^v2_ :> {v1, v2}};
variables[expr_] := FixedPoint[Replace[Variables[# /. sr], _[x_] :> x, {1}] &, expr]

variables[Sin[Subscript[x, 1]] + Cos[Subscript[x, 2]]]
(*  {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]} *)

variables[Sin[x] + Cos[y] + z^3 + Exp[d] + h + 3 h^2 + 4 h^3 + 
Integrate[Exp[p], p] + D[Sin[m]^Exp[f], m]]
(* {d, f, h, m, p, x, y, z} *)
```

Comment: Looking at the other answers I realize that Exp gives the slip with this approach. So I have updated it accordingly. I hope there are not that many cases!

Comment: Added the rule to handle your case. Probably the OP does not need this level of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are looking for is as simple as

```
vars[expr_] := DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, _Symbol, \[Infinity]]

vars[1 + y^2 + Sin[x] + Cos[x]]
```

> {y, x}

Probably there are expressions on which this will fail, but it might handle those you are interested in.