# How can I extract all the non-number symbols from an expression

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language

If I have an expression, let us say something like this:

```
Cos[3 x] + π/cofe Exp[y^(c  z)]
```

how can I get all non-number symbols in the expression which are:

> ```
> {x, cofe, y, c, z}
> ```

I tried this:

```
Cases[Cos[3 x] + π/cofe Exp[y^(c  z)], _Symbol]
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there an analogue of the Variables command for general expressions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30038).  In short, does this do what you want?: `Variables @ Level[expr, {-1}]` (where `expr` is your expression).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you. this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
expr = Cos[3 x] + \[Pi]/cofe Exp[y^(c z)];

Cases[expr, _Symbol?(! NumericQ[#] &), Infinity] // Union

(* {c, cofe, x, y, z} *)
```

In this case the Union is not necessary; however, in general it is needed to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: This is a nice answer and I am puzzled there is no built-in for this sort of thing but `Variables` (for polynomial expressions) is the closest there is. (+1)

Comment: @Bob Hanion, thanks. this is nice answer.

Comment: An alternative: `Cases[expr, Except[_?NumericQ, _Symbol], ∞] // Union`