# How to find all symbols in an expression and perform an operation on them?

Tags: replacement, pure-function, rule

========== motivation ===========

Suppose, for example, I have an incoming expression like

```
 m = (3-I)x + 4(x y)/(Cos[y])
```

I want to find all the symbols in the expression ("x" and "y" in this case) without a priori knowledge of what symbols may appear in m.
  Perhaps then I want to do something to the symbols, for example, transform each symbol #:

```
# -> u*#
```

i.e. I want to obtain from m:

```
(3-I)u x + 4(u^2 x y)/(Cos[u y])
```

In this case, I can take this result, expand in u and unitize to get:

```
Series[(3-I)u x + 4(u^2 x y)/(Cos[u y]), {u,0,1}]/.u->1
```

a series expansion to first order in both x and y, where terms x^2, y^2, ***and x y*** are dropped.

==============================================================

This is just one example though, in general, I want to know how to find the symbols in an expression and do something to them.

I've tried things similar to

```
 test = Expand[# /. Not@NumericQ :> ReplaceAll[#, z -> u z]] &;  

 (5-3 I)x + 2 y^2 //test
```

But this just returns the input unchanged, I would like it to return

```
 (5-3 I)u x + 2 u^2 y^2
```

Any help?

Comment: I feel that this question should be closed as a duplicate of [(30038)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30038) but there is just enough wiggle room that I don't wish to act alone.  If anyone agrees or disagrees please comment.

Answer (score 13):

```
m = (3 - I) x + 4 (x y)/(Cos[y]);
Variables@Level[m, {-1}]

(*{x, y}*)
```

Comment: nice use of Variables

Comment: @Nasser it should look [rather familiar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30040/121).

Answer (score 5):

"...in general, I want to know how to find the symbols in an expression..."

```
m = (3 - I) x + 4 (x y)/(Cos[y]);

sym = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[m, _Symbol, Infinity]
```

> {x, y}

"... and do something to them"

```
m /. MapThread[Rule, {sym, {u, v}}]
```

> (3 - I) u + 4 u v Sec[v]

Comment: Great! Even `m /. Function[{sym},MapThread[Rule, {sym,Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[Length@sym]}]][sym]`

Comment: This does not work. `Cases[m, _Symbol, Infinity]` will output an empty list, instead of `{m}` as it should. Using `Cases[m, _Symbol, {-1}]` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Myridium `Cases[m,_Symbol, All]` also works but maybe it's slower I do not know. It's maybe also important to mention that `Cases[Pi,_Symbol,All]` outputs `{Pi}` as `Pi` has head `Symbol`. However using `Variables` from the other answer with `Level[Pi, {-1}] // Variables` leads to an empty list. Thus, the two methods are not equivalent

Answer (score 4):

```
m = (3 - I) x + 4 (x y)/(Cos[y Pi]);
```

Since

```
Head /@ {Pi, E, GoldenRatio}  (* and others *)
```

> {Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}

`Cases` must test for more than just `Symbol`

```
m /. Thread[(var = Cases[m, _Symbol?(! NumericQ[#] &), Infinity] // Union) -> 
   u*var]
```

> (3 - I)*u*x + 4*u^2*x*y*
>        Sec[Pi*u*y]

Comment: +1, I think it safe to assume this is what the OP intended for symbol capture.

Comment: I agree, you can separate them also by context since built in symbols have ``System` `` while `x` is ``Global` ``

Comment: @BobHanlon Using `Variables` (like Algohi did) eliminates `NumericQ`

Answer (score 1):

```
m = (3 - I) x + 4 (x  y)/Cos[y];
lev = Level[m, {-1}]
Union@Cases[lev, _Symbol]

(* {x, y} *)
```

Comment: .. just saw eldo post after hitting post.... This is a little different may be. In Mathematica, we should always try to come up with 10 different ways to solve something :)