# How to generate assumptions automatically for definite integrals？

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, assumptions

In Mathematica, a trick to speed up the process of definite integrals is by adding assumptions. For example, the following codes run faster if we add such assumptions:

```
Integrate[1/(Sqrt[2 π ] sx) Exp[-(x - xi)^2/(2 sx^2)] 
1/(Sqrt[2 π ] sy)Exp[-(yi - k x - b)^2/(2 sy^2)], {x, -∞, ∞}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{23.4375, 
 ConditionalExpression[E^(-((b + k xi - yi)^2/(2 (k^2 sx^2 + sy^2))))/
(Sqrt[2 π] Sqrt[sx] Sqrt[1/sx^2 + k^2/sy^2] Sqrt[sy]), Re[1/sx^2 + k^2/sy^2] > 0]}*)


Assuming[sx > 0 && sy > 0 && xi > 0 && yi > 0 && k > 0 && b > 0, 
  Integrate[1/(Sqrt[2 π] sx) Exp[-(x - xi)^2/(2 sx^2)] 
1/(Sqrt[2 π ] sy)Exp[-(yi - k x - b)^2/(2 sy^2)], {x, -∞, ∞}]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.995044, E^(-((b + k xi - yi)^2/(2 (k^2 sx^2 + sy^2))))/
(Sqrt[2 π] Sqrt[k^2 sx^2 + sy^2])}*)
```

In most cases, the parameters in the integrals are positive or reals instead of complex, and it's effective to add assumptions for the parameters. So how to add assumptions for the parameters automatically? Just like a single code will automatically generate assumptions that all of the parameters are real or positive.

Comment: Use the `GenerateConditions -> False` option to this end `Integrate[
  1/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] sx) Exp[-(x - xi)^2/(2 sx^2)] 1/(Sqrt[
       2 \[Pi]] sy) Exp[-(yi - k x - 
         b)^2/(2 sy^2)], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False] // AbsoluteTiming` and generate conditions by hand.

Comment: This would also be useful for `Solve`,`Reduce`, `Simplify`, etc. Two alternatives that will reduce your typing are to use `Thread[{sx, sy, xi, yi, k, b} > 0] ` or `{sx, sy, xi, yi, k, b} ∈ PositiveReals` (the latter is available in MMA 12+ only) in place of `sx > 0 && sy > 0 && xi > 0 && yi > 0 && k > 0 && b > 0`, where you can get the `∈` symbol using ESC el ESC. Note that `{sx, sy, xi, yi, k, b} > 0` *will not* work, since that's telling MMA that the *list* `{sx, sy, xi, yi, k, b}` is greater than zero (and I don't know what that means), rather than that each element is greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm… I doubt if this is a good idea, but anyway:

```
SetAttributes[addpositiveassumption, HoldAll];
addpositiveassumption[int : Integrate[expr_, domain : {_, _, _} .., OptionsPattern[]]]:=
  Assuming[Complement[Variables@Level[expr, {-1}], First /@ {domain}] > 0// Thread, int]

addpositiveassumption@
  Integrate[1/(Sqrt[2 π] sx) Exp[-(x - xi)^2/(2 sx^2)] 1/(Sqrt[
        2 π] sy) Exp[-(yi - k x - b)^2/(2 sy^2)], {x, -∞, ∞}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Related:

[Extracting variables from an expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21257/1871)

[Is there an analogue of the Variables command for general expressions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30038/1871)

[How to find all symbols in an expression and perform an operation on them?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51919/1871)