# "Assume whatever makes it easier" command

Tags: assumptions

Is there a shorthand for telling Mathematica to assume things like "everything is a positive real unless specified otherwise" etc? It get's really tedious for expressions with many parameters that, in principle, shouldn't make things difficult but never the less confuses Mathematica because it is trying to look for more general solutions that are needed.

Edit: I was talking about having a command that can be appended in Integrate[] DSolve[] as a short hand for one by one specifying each parameter to be a positive real.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/249328/1871

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate assumptions automatically for definite integrals？](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249328/how-to-generate-assumptions-automatically-for-definite-integrals)

Comment: Assuming "everything is a positive real unless specified otherwise" is not the same as assuming "whatever makes it easier".  Which do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a shorthand for telling Mathematica to assume things like
> "everything is a positive real unless specified otherwise" etc?

You did not give an example.

Given an expression, you can automatically find all the variables in it and then apply the assumption on this. Here is an example

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
expr=y[z]+x+Pi+m/Sin[a]+b[0]*Exp[h];
vars=DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr,any_/;Head[any]===Symbol
        &&Not[MemberQ[Attributes[any],Constant]],Infinity];
myassum=Assumptions->Thread[vars>0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can do

```
 Simplify[expr,myassum]
```

Or to make them global do

```
$Assumptions=Thread[vars>0]
Simplify[expr]
```

Change the assumption to anything else you want.

btw, the above does not answer **"Assume whatever makes it easier" command** since I have no idea how this could be implemented in Mathematica. You could give the new `LLMFunction` a try and see if chatGPT could figure it out, it sounds like it needs AI to implement but I am no expert on this.

Comment: Why not Solve[......, PositiveReals]`?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the OP said **assume things like "everything is a positive real unless specified otherwise" etc?** so I assumed they wanted this for Any command in Mathematica that uses assumptions (`Simplify, Integrate` etc...). Also, for `Solve` , the domain applies _only_ to the variable being solved for and for the domain of the solution. It does not apply to any other symbol in the expression itself. (that is why giving an example always helps).

Comment: THAT certainly wasn't clear to me.  I don't know how one states that every variable, every term is (say) positive real, and what would happen then if you typed `Solve[x == -2, x]`.  Seems extremely risky....

Comment: @DavidG.Stork **I don't know how one states that every variable, every term is (say) positive real,** Well, that is what my answer is meant to make it easier to do by automating this part. Anyway, the question is fuzzy since no example was given. That is why I also suggested to use A.I. as it is better at answering fuzzy questions than Mathematica.

Comment: Btw, Maple has [assuming](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=assuming) command, which actually does this. For example one can do `solve(equation,x) assuming real` where it says **The expression assuming property calling sequence evaluates the expression under the assumption property on all names in expression.**  note where it says **all names in expression**. i.e. It automatically applies the assumption on each symbol/name in the expression. I use this alot and can be handy.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Try it: `Solve[x == -2, x, PositiveReals]`. (Is that what you meant?)

Comment: Yes... of course I tried it.  There's no solution given that constraint.  Does the OP really know ahead of time that not a single problem confronted will be consistent with a global constraint as suggested?  And what's the point anyway?  Why focus on "what's simple" when *Mathematica* handles extraordinarily complex equations anyway?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If simply adding, PositiveReals instead of Assumptions->{whole&& lot&& of&& stuff}  worked, that would have been great. The reason I want to do this, is because I dont want to wait minutes for a generalization that might not even exist.

Comment: @Gappy Hilmore:  Can you give one example?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork sooooo... Im gonna cheat and give an example of an integer example rather than positive real, because I most recently came across that.  `Integrate[Exp[-Sin[x]^2] Cos[2 n x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]` This integral evaluates to `(2 \[Pi] BesselI[n, 1/2])/Sqrt[E]` for integer n. But Mathematica cannot arrive at this unless you manually plug in a few integers and notice the pattern. Not even "assumptions" works, now that I attempted it, so maybe not a perfect example but I think it is easy to see certain assumptions being critical for evaluating integrals.

Comment: "Not even 'assumptions' works, now that I attempted it, so maybe not a perfect example."  Yep.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249328/how-to-generate-assumptions-automatically-for-definite-integrals This example illustrates how much slower it is, even for a very simple integral

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry if I misunderstood. I meant `Solve[x == -2, x, PositiveReals]` means what I thought you said, "how one states that every variable, every term is (say) positive real, and what would happen then if you typed "Solve[x == -2, x]`". And it returns an empty solution set, since `x` positive and `x == -2` are contradictory.