# Automatically assign solutions to equation as constants

Tags: assignment, automation

Consider the following code:

```
ClearAll[K, L, λ, q, r, w]

TC[K_, L_, q] := w*L + r*K + 10*q
Phi[K_, L_, λ_] := TC[K, L, q] - λ*(10*K^(4/5)*(L - 40)^(1/5) - q)
Phi[K, L, λ]

FullSimplify[{
  D[Phi[K, L, λ], K],
  D[Phi[K, L, λ], L],
  D[Phi[K, L, λ], λ]
  }]

FullSimplify[
 Solve[{
   D[Phi[K, L, λ], K] == 0,
   D[Phi[K, L, λ], L] == 0,
   D[Phi[K, L, λ], λ] == 0
   }, {K, L, λ}]
 ]

r = 64;
w = 32;
FullSimplify[TC[K, L, q]]
```

Is it possible to automatically assign the real-valued solutions for `K` and `L` to get the output

```
2 (640 + (5 + 4 2^(1/5)) q)
```

with executing the last command?

**Update**

After hints from Artes, I've managed to always get the function `TC` for real-valued `K` and `L`. However, how do I print only the *real-values* [which I forgot to mention the first time I updated the question] of `K` and `L` when I solve the system of equations? When executing

```
F[k_, l_] := 10*k^(4/5)*(l - 40)^(1/5)
TC[k_, l_, q_] := w*l + r*k + 10*q
Phi[k_, l_, λ_] := TC[k, l, q] - λ*(F[k, l] - q)
expressions = {D[Phi[k, l, λ], k], D[Phi[k, l, λ], l], D[Phi[k, l, λ, λ]};
FullSimplify[Solve[expressions == {0, 0, 0}, {k, l, λ}]]
```

I get five solutions;

```
{{k -> (q w^(1/5))/(5 2^(3/5) r^(1/5)), 
  l -> 40 + (q r^(4/5))/(20 2^(3/5) w^(4/5)), λ] -> (
   r^(4/5) w^(1/5))/(
   4 2^(3/5))}, {k -> -(((-1)^(1/5) q w^(1/5))/(5 2^(3/5) r^(1/5))), 
  l -> 40 - ((-1)^(1/5) q r^(4/5))/(20 2^(3/5) w^(4/5)), λ -> 
   r^(4/5) w^(1/5) Root[-1 + 8192 #1^5 &, 2]}, {k -> ((-1)^(2/5) q w^(
    1/5))/(5 2^(3/5) r^(1/5)), 
  l -> 1/40 (1600 + ((-2)^(2/5) q r^(4/5))/w^(
      4/5)), λ -> ((-1)^(2/5) r^(4/5) w^(1/5))/(
   4 2^(3/5))}, {k -> -(((-1)^(3/5) q w^(1/5))/(5 2^(3/5) r^(1/5))), 
  l -> 40 - ((-(1/2))^(3/5) q r^(4/5))/(
    20 w^(4/5)), λ -> -(((-1)^(3/5) r^(4/5) w^(1/5))/(
    4 2^(3/5)))}, {k -> ((-1)^(4/5) q w^(1/5))/(5 2^(3/5) r^(1/5)), 
  l -> 40 + ((-1)^(4/5) q r^(4/5))/(
    20 2^(3/5) w^(4/5)), λ -> ((-1)^(4/5) r^(4/5) w^(1/5))/(
   4 2^(3/5))}}
```

P.S. `q`, `r`, and `w` are all positive numbers.

Comment: `Solve[FullSimplify[TC[K, L, q]] == 2 (640 + (5 + 4 2^(1/5)) q), {K, 
  L}]`

Comment: @belisarius I mean: If I execute `FullSimplify[
 Solve[{
   D[Phi[K, L, λ], K] == 0,
   D[Phi[K, L, λ], L] == 0,
   D[Phi[K, L, λ], λ] == 0
   }, {K, L, λ}]
 ]`, I get the solution `K -> (q w^(1/5))/(5 2^(3/5) r^(1/5)), L -> 
 40 + (q r^(4/5))/(20 2^(3/5) w^(4/5))`. Can I *automatically* assign these values to `K` and `L` and therefore get `2 (640 + (5 + 4 2^(1/5)) q)` if I execute `r = 64;
w = 32;
FullSimplify[TC[K, L, q] ]`?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/193

Comment: @belisarius Indeed! `:)` The only thing: Can I make it automatically choose the real-valued solution instead of, say, the first one?

Comment: @belisarius I've found [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/28248) but I can't get any of the methods to work. Can you help? `:)`

Comment: This post is what you are looking for [How to find lattice points on a line segment?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16678/how-to-find-lattice-points-on-a-line-segment/16705#16705), especially II solution. If you need to specify the real domain use e.g. `Solve[ eqs, vars, Reals]`.

Comment: @Artes Can I make you give an answer, using this method? (1) I'm not sure how to use it and (2) I can accept your question and thereby finish my question.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I'm not going to answer your question since: 1. I don't like defining functions depending on parameters which are not explicit variables (it isn't appropriate practice) e.g. `TC` depends on `w` and `r`. 2. You shouldn't use capital `K`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg By the way you can do this: `TC[k, l, q] /. 
  Solve[{D[Phi[k, l, λ], k] == 0, 
    D[Phi[k, l, λ], l] == 0, 
    D[Phi[k, l, λ], λ] == 0}, {k, l, λ}, 
   Reals] // Simplify`

Comment: @Artes Hmmm. I'm reather tired and can't think properly right now, I can feel. Can I make you give a full answer (with your preferred changes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply save the `FullSimplify` result (the one before the `r = ...` assignment), say as "res".
Then use

```
FullSimplify[ TC[K,L,q]]/. res // FullSimplify//First
```

gives exactly the result you posted. Remove the first (and add a rule to filter only reals) to substitute all real solutions.

Per your update, this should return the $k$ and $l$ (along with any other solution components) where $k$ and $l$ are restricted to reals:

```
Pick[(res), Refine[ # ∈ Reals, Assumptions -> {q, w, r} ∈ Reals 
                    && 0 < q && 0 < w && 0 < r] & /@ ({k, l} /. res)]
```

Comment: On the top of the page you find a "help" link. There you can choose different help topics. One of them is [how to format a post properly](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @halirutan - cheers, and thanks for editing!

Comment: I made a huge omission in my first update to the question. See the updated question.

Comment: @Svend - ah- I thought the question a bit simple. I've added to my original answer. Again, assuming you put the solve set into 'res', this should return the set where k and l are reals.

Comment: Great. Thank you.