# 1D quasicrystal: points on a line nearest to points on a lattice

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, manipulate, physics, lattices

I have a simple lattice / line manipulation:

```
Manipulate[r = 10; b = {{0, r}, {r, 0}};
l1 = Flatten[Table[i b[[1]] + j b[[2]], {i, 0, r}, {j, 0, r}], 1]/r;
Clear[a, b]; b = a /. Solve[a + y == 90, a][[1]]; x = y Pi/180;
g = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {If[y <= 45, r/Cos[x], r/Cos[b Pi/180]], 0}}]];
rot = l : Line[pts_] :> Rotate[l, x, {0, 0}];
Show[Graphics[Point[l1], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1], g /. rot], {{y, 45}, 0, 90}]
```

and would like to add points (that move with the manipulation) on the line that are perpendicular to the nearest points of the lattice, as shown below:

[image]

It would be a bonus if the perpendicular joining lines appeared also.

The only way I can think of pursuing this is to use something like `Nearest`, `FrobeniusSolve`, etc. (have been looking at the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16678/how-to-find-lattice-points-on-a-line-segment) with little success so far) to generate data for something along the lines of:

```
f = Graphics[Point[{{0, 0}, data, {If[y <= 45, r/Cos[x], 12], 0}}]];
rot1 = l : Point[pts_] :> Rotate[l, x, {0, 0}];
Show[Graphics[Point[l1], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1], g /. rot, f /. rot1]
```

## Note:

As noted by Vitaliy Kaurov below, the defining 'band' (dashed in the diagram) would not (necessarily) be symmetric about the main line. In this instance, the ratio of smaller to larger is the golden ratio. This is more obvious when looking at central red line in the above image - compare with:

[image]

I would ideally like this band width to be adjustable within the manipulation, but this is a minor concern.

## Update

A minor modification of george2079's code

```
a = N[1/2 (Sqrt[(2/(5 + Sqrt[5]))] + Sqrt[10/(5 + Sqrt[5])])];
b = N[Sqrt[2/(5 + Sqrt[5])]];
Manipulate[Module[{grid, f, lndat, near, lnpts, lines1, lines2}, band = 1;
grid = Flatten[Outer[List, Range[-4, 4], Range[-4, 4]], 1];
f[x_] := m x;
lines1 = Select[pointlinedis[{{{0, 0}, {4, f[4]}}, grid}], 
Norm[Subtract @@ #] < a band &];
lines2 = Select[pointlinedis[{{{0, 0}, {4, f[4]}}, grid}], 
Norm[Subtract @@ #] < b band &];
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> 4], 
Plot[f[x] - b band/Cos[ArcTan[m]], {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> 4], 
Plot[f[x] + a band/Cos[ArcTan[m]], {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> 4], 
Graphics[{{Opacity[.5], PointSize[.015], Point[grid]},
{Orange, Thickness[.005], Line /@ lines1}, {Red, Opacity[.5], 
PointSize[.03], Point[#[[1]] & /@ lines1]}, {PointSize[.015], 
Blue, Point[#[[2]]] & /@ lines1}}], AspectRatio -> 1]], {{m, N[Pi/5]}, -10, 10}]
```

gives

[image]

which is nearly what I was after, but I would really like to exclude the points outside the lower line. If I swap `lines1` for `lines2` in bottom 3 lines of code, they are excluded, but so are some of points in top band. I have tried playing around with various `If` combinations, but can't seem to select points in upper band separately to points in lower band.

Also, point near $\{3,3\}$ shouldn't be included (though george2079 does note that this may happen in his answer).

Comment: 1D quasicrystal with Fibonacci sequence of longer/shorter intervals ?

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov Yep, that's the one - but would like to create manipulation that shows what would happen where line is other than $\phi$.

Comment: How you define the band of points which to select for perpendicular lines?

Comment: Ideally, that would be adjustable within the manipulation - sorry - forgot to add that in :/ - will correct in question.

Comment: I don't think you put mathematical definition of bands - so no one understands what you need. If they are based on know golden ration distances you should explain that in the post. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Bands are slightly different distances from main line ([golden ratio](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j9fOb.png) in this case) - compare with central red line in image above.

Comment: I would really like to be able to manipulate them separately though - (with default at golden ratio).

Comment: I think nearest to a line points are defined without any band - they are actually the band. Are you saying you would like to expand the band to include not nearest points?

Comment: Yes - I suppose I am :/ ... sorry for not being clear!! :/

Comment: ... Nearest within a given tolerance value :/

Comment: for your asymmetric bands you need to select based on side, something like `(Norm[Subtract @@ #] < b band && Det[{(Subtract @@ #), {4, f[4]}}] < 0 )&` The sign of the determinant determines which side of the line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So you guys know - quasicrystals are cool structures that can consist of finite number of parts which can be arranged in never repeating - aperiodic - pattern. Thing here is called projection method from a regular lattice.

http://www.nature.com/nmat/journal/v3/n11/fig_tab/nmat1244_F3.html

Interestingly if you know Fibonacci rabbits problem - that is also a 1D quasicrystal because sequence of 0 and 1 there is aperiodic.

```
Animate[
 Module[
  {grid, f, lndat, near, lnpts, lines, bnd1, bnd2},

  grid = Flatten[Outer[List, Range[-6, 6], Range[-6, 6]], 1];

  f[x_] := m x;

  lndat = 
   Select[{#, f[#]} & /@ Range[-6, 6, .01], -6 < #[[2]] < 6 &];

  near = Union[Flatten[Nearest[grid, #] & /@ lndat, 1]];

  lnpts = First[Nearest[lndat, #]] & /@ near;

  lines = Line /@ Thread[{near, lnpts}];

  {bnd1[x], bnd2[x]} = 
   m x + (#2 - 
        m #1) & @@@ (Sort[#, 
         EuclideanDistance @@ #1 > EuclideanDistance @@ #2 &] & /@ 
       GatherBy[
        Thread[{near, lnpts}], #[[1, 1]] - #[[2, 1]] > 0 &])[[All, 1, 
      1]];

  Show[
   Plot[Evaluate@{f[x], bnd1[x], bnd2[x]}, {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> 4,
     PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed, Dashed}, 
    Filling -> {2 -> {3}}],
   Graphics[{
     {Opacity[.5], PointSize[.015], Point[grid]},
     {Red, Opacity[.5], PointSize[.03], Point[near]},
     {Orange, Thickness[.005], lines},
     {PointSize[.015], Blue, Point[lnpts]}}]
   , AspectRatio -> 1]
  ]
 , {{m, -4, "slope"}, -4, 4}, AnimationRunning -> False, 
 AnimationRate -> .5]
```

[image]

Comment: this is fantastic! I was worried that it might take too long to calculate - but this responds instantly! :)

Comment: @martin Nearest is main alg, but it is fast ;-)

Comment: Yes, it certainly is! :)

Comment: Haven't had a close look yet, but would it be fairly straightforward to add a tolerance band as per your comments above?

Comment: @martin I added bands

Comment: That's great, but don't the bands define the nearest points, as opposed to being a consequence of them?

Comment: @martin how you then define bands?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov What are you using for the screen captures?

Comment: @belisarius [**LICEcap**](http://www.cockos.com/licecap)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Nice app!Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here you are with the bands -- note also an (I think) improvement over the brute force fine discretization of the line:  (I'm Not sure if that improved performance, but it didn't hurt and it looks cleaner)

*caveat* I think my little trick thinning down the `lndat` list is not guaranteed to find all of the strictly nearest points.  It seems to work for the square grid but study that carefully if its critical.

```
 pointlinedis[{line_, pointlist_}] := 
     Module[{u = Subtract @@ line, mean = Plus @@ line/2},
        {#, (mean - u  #/2) &@(-(2 ( # - mean).u )/u .u) } & /@ pointlist ]
 Manipulate[Module[{grid, f, lndat, near, lnpts, lines},
   grid = Flatten[Outer[List, Range[-4, 4], Range[-4, 4]], 1];
   f[x_] := m x;
   lndat = pointlinedis[ {{{0, 0}, {4, f[4]}}, grid }][[;; , 2]];
   near = Union[Flatten[Nearest[grid, #] & /@ lndat, 1]];
   lines = pointlinedis[ {{{0, 0}, {4, f[4]}}, near }];
   zneg = Select[ lines , Det[{(Subtract @@ #), {4, f[4]}}] < 0 &];
   znegoff = Max[Norm[Subtract @@ #] & /@ zneg];
   zpos = Select[ lines , Det[{(Subtract @@ #), {4, f[4]}}] > 0 &];
   zposoff = Max[Norm[Subtract @@ #] & /@ zpos];
   Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> 4],
        Plot[f[x] + {-znegoff , zposoff }/Cos[ArcTan[m]], {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> 4],
        Graphics[{{Opacity[.5], PointSize[.015], Point[grid]}, {Red, 
         Opacity[.5], PointSize[.03], Point[near]}, {Orange, 
         Thickness[.005], Line /@ lines}, {PointSize[.015], Blue, 
         Point[#[[2]]] & /@ lines}}], AspectRatio -> 1]], {{m, 1}, -7, 7}]
```

[image]

### specified bands

It is actually a good bit simpler if you want to just specify the cutoff distance:

```
Manipulate[Module[{grid, f, lndat, near, lnpts, lines},
  band = 2;
  grid = Flatten[Outer[List, Range[-4, 4], Range[-4, 4]], 1];
  f[x_] := m x;
  lines = Select[ pointlinedis[{{{0, 0}, {4, f[4]}}, grid}], 
     Norm[Subtract @@ #] < band &];
  Show[
    Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> 4], 
    Plot[f[x] + {-band, band}/Cos[ArcTan[m]], {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> 4],
   Graphics[{{Opacity[.5], PointSize[.015], Point[grid]}, {Red, 
       Opacity[.5], PointSize[.03], Point[#[[1]] & /@ lines]}, {Orange,
       Thickness[.005], Line /@ lines}, {PointSize[.015], Blue, 
       Point[#[[2]]] & /@ lines}}], AspectRatio -> 1]], {{m, 1}, -7, 7}]
```

If you wanted both (true "nearest" and a cutoff) you can just use this `lines=Select` construct in the first example`

Comment: bands are great, but their respective distances from the main line would ideally be independently adjustable (so that one could be adjusted to be closer to the main line than the other) - thereby **defining** the nearest points **within that specified tolerance band**. The above example (and what Vitaliy Kaurov is referencing in his opening paragraph) is based on Fibonacci ratio - and *defines the nearest points*, rather than being a consequence of them. - See [here](http://blog.kleinproject.org/?p=863).

Comment: That is great - I will have a play with that & see if I can get them moving independently of one another :)

Comment: Could you explain what pointlinedis does?

Comment: `pointlinedis` just finds the closest point on the line for each point in a list of points.

Comment: @ george2079, I have updated question with slight modification to your code. Nearly there, but would appreciate it if you could cast your eye over it! :)

Answer (score 4):

Alternate answer, this is an exact analytic approach to the nearest point problem:
(not i think precisely what @martin was after, but its an interesting problem and others may find it useful)

```
 lb = -1;ub = 1;
 pts0 = Select[Flatten[
   Table[ {i, j}, {i, 2 lb, 2 ub , .2}, {j, 2 lb , 2 ub , .2}], 1] ,Norm[#] < 1 &];
 intv[ p_, pn_] := 
 If[(pn[[1]] != p[[1]]),
    Piecewise[ {
       {Interval[{lb,  #}], pn[[1]] > p[[1]] &&  # > lb },
       {Interval[{ #, ub}], pn[[1]] < p[[1]] && # < ub},
       {Interval[], True}}] &@
            (  (pn + p).{1, #[[2]]/#[[1]] } &@(pn - p)/2 ),
    If[ p[[2]] <= pn[[2]], Interval[{lb, ub}], Interval[]]]
 Manipulate[
    pts = RotationMatrix[theta].# & /@ pts0;
    oo = First@Last@Reap[Do[(If[# =!= Interval[],
       Sow[{pts[[i]], #}]] &@
       (IntervalIntersection @@ (intv[pts[[i]], #] & /@ pts)))  ,
         {i, Length[pts]}]];
    band = Sort[oo[[;; , 1, 2]]][[{-1, 1}]];
    Show[Graphics[{Line[{{-1.25, 0}, {1.25, 0}}], 
                   Line[{{0, -1.25}, {0, 1.25}}],
             Rotate[{
              {Thick, Hue[RandomReal[{0, 1}]],
                 Line[{{#[[1]], 0}, {#[[2]], 0}}]} & /@
                   Partition[ Sort@Flatten[List @@ # & /@ oo[[;; , 2]]] , 2, 1],
              {Dashed, Line[{{lb, #}, {ub, #}}] & /@ band},
              {Red, PointSize[.02], Point[oo[[;; , 1]]]},
              {PointSize[.01], Point[pts]},
              {Line[{{#[[2, 1, 1]], 0}, #[[1]], {#[[2, 1, 2]], 0}}] & /@ oo}},
                -theta, {0, 0}]}]], {{theta, .1}, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

The color coding indicates the portions of the line that own each of the near points.
(It would be trivial to show the perpendiculars as well but it gets a bit cluttered.)

A random point example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: A really interesting take on it - the random point one is great :)