# How to count the integer grid numbers defined by inequalities?

Tags: grid-layouts, inequalities

I have the following code to show a red area defined by inequalities:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
p = Reduce[y <= 3/10 x + 18 && y > x^2/8, {x, y}]
r = RegionPlot[p, {x, -15, 18}, {y, -5, 25}, 
   GridLines -> {Table[i, {i, -15, 18}], Table[j, {j, -5, 25}]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[{Opacity[0.5], Red}]];
bg = Graphics[{Opacity[0.2], Yellow, Rectangle[{-16, -6}, {19, 26}]}];
range = First /@ 
  Differences /@ (PlotRange /. Options[r]); target = 1; Show[{r, bg}, 
 AspectRatio -> (Last[range]/First[range]/target)]
```

which shows:

[image]

How can I count those integer grids and highlight them with colored dots?

Comment: Closely related: [How to find lattice points on a line segment?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16678/how-to-find-lattice-points-on-a-line-segment). If there are many solutions `Reduce` can't be efficient however a neat approach with `FrobeniusSolve` can yield all interesting solutions as in one of the answers in the link. For benchmarks see this answer [Finding the number of solutions to a diophantine equation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10562/finding-the-number-of-solutions-to-a-diophantine-equation/10569#10569).

Comment: Thank you! This link and the new command are very useful!

Comment: @Artes Those links show efficient methods, as such problems go. But they require polytope regions (i.e. linear inequalities).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do :

```
p = ImplicitRegion[y <= 3/10 x + 18 && y > x^2/8, {x, y}]

points = Reduce[Element[{x, y}, p], {x, y}, Integers]

pp = Cases[points, x == xx_ && y == yy_ -> {xx, yy}]

pp // Length
(* 286 *) 

Show[RegionPlot[p], ListPlot[pp]]
```

[image]

Comment: You can directly to pp using `Reduce` with `pp = {x, y} /. {Reduce[Element[{x, y}, p], {x, y}, Integers] // ToRules};`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, I knew there must have been a better way.

Answer (score 8):

```
eqn = y <= 3/10 x + 18 && y > x^2/8;
sol = Reduce[eqn, {x, y}, Integers];
Length @ sol
(* 286 *)
points = {x, y} /. {ToRules[sol]}; (* thanks: BobHanlon *)
RegionPlot[eqn, {x, -15, 18}, {y, -5, 25}, 
           GridLines -> {Range[-15, 18], Range[-5, 25]}, 
           PlotStyle -> Directive[{Opacity[0.5], Red}], 
           Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[points]}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can go directly to points using `Reduce` with `points = {x, y} /. {Reduce[eqn, {x, y}, Integers] // ToRules};`

Comment: @BobHanlon, thank you; will update with you suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another solution using **V10** functionalities:

```
region = ImplicitRegion[y <= 3/10 x + 18 && y > x^2/8, {{x, -15, 18}, {y, -5, 25}}];

lis = Tuples[{Range[-15, 18], Range[-5, 25]}];
```

We create a `RegionMemberFunction`

```
rm = RegionMember[region];
```

Now we select from `lis` the points that are in the `region`:

```
in = Select[lis, rm];

Length @ in
```

> 286

Visualize:

```
out = Complement[lis, in];

Show[RegionPlot[region], Graphics[{Red, Point[in],Green, Point[out]}], 
                         PlotRange -> {{-15, 18}, {-5, 25}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]