# speeding up Solve(ing) the Diophantine equation

Tags: equation-solving

Trying to solve the Diophantine equation (or variation?) using `Solve` in order to generate some chemical formulas. I need to generate all possible solutions. The code is following:

```
mx1 = 1007825; mx2 = 12000000; mx3 = 14003074; mx4 = 15994915; mx5 = 18998403; 
mx6 = 30973762; mx7 = 31972071; mx8 = 34968853; mx9 = 78918338; mx10 = 126904468;
up = 722126458;
dn = 722120458;
x1max = 70; x2max = 125; x3max = 25; x4max = 27; x5max = 10; x6max = \
0; x7max = 0; x8max = 0; x9max = 0; x10max = 0;

Solve[{dn <= 
     mx1*x1 + mx2*x2 + mx3*x3 + mx4*x4 + mx5*x5 + mx6*x6 + mx7*x7 + 
      mx8*x8 + mx9*x9 + mx10*x10 <= up, x1max >= x1 >= 0, 
    x2max >= x2 >= 10, x3max >= x3 >= 0, x4max >= x4 >= 0, 
    x5max >= x5 >= 0, x6max >= x6 >= 0, x7max >= x7 >= 0, 
    x8max >= x8 >= 0, x9max >= x9 >= 0, x10max >= x10 >= 0}, {x1, x2, 
    x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10}, Integers]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.2670152, Null}`

As I am increasing number of variables time increase.
Addition of `x6max=10 - time=2.15s; x7max=9 - time=32.34s`

with addition of  `x8max=8`, `x9max=8` and `x10max=2` timing is ??

I am looking for suggestions how to speed up the process. One to several seconds time frame would be great.

`Reduce` and `FindInstance` perform roughly similar. Brute forcing doesn’t work effectively either.

Tried to work out solution in different way; like generating 2 sets (e.g. for `x1` to `x5` and `x6` to `x6`) with all possible combinations, sorting them (decreasing/increasing order) and than sum elements. It doesn’t perform fast either considering 1 million element tables.

Comment: I recommend using `FrobeniusSolve` instead of  `Solve` when one deals with diophantine equations. See this answer [Finding the number of solutions to a diophantine equation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10562/finding-the-number-of-solutions-to-a-diophantine-equation/10569#10569) for encouragement. This might be another one [How to find lattice points on a line segment?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16678/how-to-find-lattice-points-on-a-line-segment/16705#16705)